# What Does It Mean That Reputation (Its Increase, Actually) Is Capped at 200 Per Day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Suppose a person starts out with say, a 1000 reputation, and earns 210 in one day. My understanding is that at the end of the day, the reputation is 1200 (based on the 200 cap).

What happens to the extra 10 points? Are they carried over to the FOLLOWING day, so that reputation is 1210 as of the "second" day? (That's assuming no cap on the second day's reputation.) Or are the extra 10 points just "lost?"

Answer (score 3):

From the main meta site, the points are lost:

[What happens when you hit 200 reputation by upvotes for one day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/what-happens-when-you-hit-200-reputation-by-upvotes-for-one-day)

It's worth noting that the 200 point limit is only for upvotes.  Accepted answers and awarded bounties are not limited.

Comment: Basically, it means that you have to space out your questions (as I have started to do) so you don't get more than 200 upvotes a day. (In the "early days" I was exceeding 100 on certain days.) Was this the intent?